# Suppose that we have a collection of $12$ sets, each of which has $8$ elements......

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that we have a collection of $12$ sets, each of which has $8$ elements.
Every pair of sets shares $6$ elements, any collection of $3$ sets shares $4$ elements, and
no collection of $4$ sets shares any elements. How many elements are there in total?

I do not have any idea to solve this problem.Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Here's an idea: use the inclusion-exclusion formula.

Comment: @bof  $12 \times 8 - \binom 82\times 6 + \binom 83\times 4 =152$

Comment: Why $\binom82$? You have $12$ sets, so $\binom{12}2$ pairs of sets . . .

Comment: @bof  $12 \times 8 - \binom {12}{2}\times 6 + \binom {12}{3}\times 4 =580$

Comment: But in total we have 96 elements.

Comment: Good point. You've shown that the data is inconsistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation described is impossible. Consider four of the sets, $A,B,C$, and $D$. Let $W=A\cap B\cap C$, $X=A\cap B\cap D$, $Y=A\cap C\cap D$, and $Z=B\cap C\cap D$. The sets $W,X,Y$, and $Z$ are pairwise disjoint sets of cardinality $4$, and $A\supseteq W\cup X\cup Y$, so $|A|\ge 12$, contradicting the hypothesis that $|A|=8$.